# Printing 2D array in a for loop crashes program

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, printf, nested-loops

I am new to the programming language C. I am trying to make a simple game where you can walk around in a 2D space and place or remove blocks. I am using the terminal for the graphics. The problem is, I expect the program to print an `X` character followed by 24 blank lines, however, the program just straight up crashes. I don't understand how or why my code could have crashed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char map[79][24]; /* create the map */
    int xPosition = 0, yPosition = 0; /* set the x and y position for the player */
    int x, y; /* create variables for the for loop */
    for (y = 0; y <= 24; y++) { 
        for (x = 0; x <= 79; x++) {
            map[x][y] = ' ';
        }
    } /* initialize the map */
    map[xPosition][yPosition] = 'X'; /* put the player in their position */
    for (y = 0; y <= 24; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x <= 79; x++) {
            printf("%c", map[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } /* display the map on screen */
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain the problem and show the correct way to do it. Thanks in advance - justAnotherCoder

EDIT: The problem is fixed now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using uninitialised variable `x`.

Comment: You are muddling up your `x` and `y` variables in the `for` loop statements.

Comment: @H.S. In my code it clearly says `int x, y`. So how is it uninitalised?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks. I fixed it. But now it crashes.

Comment: @justAnotherCoder from #6.7.9p10 - _If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate._

Comment: You need to change your `y <= 24` tests to just `y < 24` (and similarly for the `x` tests); otherwise, you're going out of bounds on the arrays, as the last element is at `n-1`.

Comment: @justAnotherCoder By the way I countered 28 members with the nick justAnotherCoder. It is a whole team!:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior at least because even in the first loop there is used an initialized variable x

```
int x, y; /* create variables for the for loop */
for (y = 0; x <= 24; x++) { 
            ^^^^^^^
    for (x = 0; y <= 79; y++) {
        map[x][y] = ' ';
    }
} /* initialize the map */
```

And moreover the conditions `x <= 24` and `y <= 79` in the loops are also invalid.

The loops do not have sense.

The array `map` is declared like

```
char map[79][24];
```

that is it has `79` rows and `24` columns.

So the loops should look like

```
for (x = 0; x < 79; x++) { 
    for (y = 0; y < 24; y++) {
        map[x][y] = ' ';
    }
} /* initialize the map */
```

The same indices and conditions should be use in the second pair of loops.

Instead of the loops that initialize the array you could use the standard string function `memset` like

```
#include <string.h>

//,,,

memset( map, ' ', 79 * 24 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program (for simplicity I reduced the number of rows from 79 to 24)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 24, N = 24 };

    char map[M][N];

    memset( map, ' ', M * N );

    map[0][0] = 'X';


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N + 2; i++ )
    {
        putchar( '-' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf( "|%.*s|\n", N, map[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N + 2; i++ )
    {
        putchar( '-' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
--------------------------
|X                       |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
--------------------------
```

**Edit:** Take into account that after you changed your code nevertheless if to ignore the invalid conditions then you are outputting a figure that contains 80 columns and 25 rows instead of outputting a figure with 25 columns and 80 rows

```
for (y = 0; y <= 24; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x <= 79; x++) {
        printf("%c", map[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} /* display the map on screen */
```

because the inner loop outputs sequentially in one line 80 characters.

Comment: I thought it would be 80 rows and 25 columns since it includes the number 0

Comment: @justAnotherCoder The declarations of the array shows how many rows and columns it has. So as the indices start from 0 then  you have to use either the condition with the operator < or !=.

Answer (score 1):

Check for loops condition you have written in your code. for achieving the expected result use below modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char map[79][24]; /* create the map */
    int xPosition = 0, yPosition = 0; /* set the x and y position for the player */
    int x, y; /* create variables for the for loop */
    for (x = 0; x < 24; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 79; y++) {
            map[x][y] = ' ';
        }
    } /* initialize the map */
    map[xPosition][yPosition] = 'X'; /* put the player in their position */
    for (x = 0; x < 24; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 79; y++) {
            printf("%c", map[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } /* display the map on screen */
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit :** keep the variables scope with assigned blocks of memory.

Comment: No! `x <= 24` should be `x < 24`, etc.

Comment: @justAnotherCoder this code post on you initial question now you have again edit your code and claiming nothing is changed. if you see in for loop you initialized like for(y=0, x <= 24, y++) etc. these changes i have done and paste for your understanding.

Comment: @dragon Sorry. I didn't notice until I had changed mine.

Comment: it's ok.. @justAnotherCoder